# SSRS Report Showing Extra Spaces

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

Design Mode
  ![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/udOQS.jpg

In Browser
![2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeOSl.png
SSRS Report Extra White space is Coming , i Highlighted that in yellow color . Pleae take a look at the attached image.

Answer (score 0):

Check your margins --> Report|Report Properties|Margins

Answer (score 0):

ensure the tablix is place at 0X0 and ensure consume containerwhitespace property is set to true